# Inequality with complex sine

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I am trying to solve this problem:

Show $$|\sin z| \leq \cosh y,\  z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$$

Using that information or not, deduce that:

$$|\sin z|\leq \left(\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}\right)|z|,\ z\in \{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z|< 1\}.$$

The first inequality I solved. I tried to solve the second using the first, but so far the most I got was the following:

Fix $0<y<1$ and restricting $cosh y$ the interval $ [0, y] $, by The Mean-Value Theorem $\exists\ t\in (0,y)$ such that $$\frac{\cosh y - \cosh 0 }{y}=\sinh t \rightarrow \cosh y=\sinh t \cdot y +1$$.

How $\sinh y$ is increasing from $[0,+\infty)$,

$$\sinh t \cdot y +1< \sinh 1 \cdot y +1 \rightarrow \cosh y < \sinh 1\cdot y+1< \sinh 1\cdot |z|+1$$

So:

$$|\sin z|\leq \left(\frac{e-e^{-1}}{2}\right)|z|+1$$

Of course I'm considering $0<y<1$ because $|z|<1$. And still remains to check the case where $y=0$.

Comment: Look at $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z}$, use the maximum principle.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your hint @DanielFischer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show the inequality

$$\lvert \sin z\rvert \leqslant \sinh 1 \cdot \lvert z\rvert\tag{1}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$. Looking at the entire function

$$f(z) = \begin{cases}\;\;\, 1 &, z = 0 \\ \dfrac{\sin z}{z} &, z \neq 0, \end{cases}$$

the inequality $(1)$ is equivalent to $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \sinh 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, and by the maximum modulus principle, that is equivalent to $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \sinh 1$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, which we can reduce to

$$\lvert \sin z\rvert \leqslant \sinh 1\tag{2}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$.

But $(2)$ is an easy consequence of

$$\lvert \sin z\rvert \leqslant \sinh \lvert z\rvert,\tag{3}$$

which follows quickly from the relation between $\sin$ and $\sinh$ and some properties of $\sinh$, or directly from the power series expansions.